# How can I use the same ObjectId for 2 collections using MongoEngine ReferenceField?

Tags: mongodb, one-to-one, mongoengine

I have a fairly heavy `User` document class, and I would like to cut it in two pieces: the user's profile (name and avatar) in a `UserProfile` document and the rest in a `User` document, like this (using MongoEngine):

```
from mongoengine import *

class User(Document):
    login = StringField()
    password = StringField()
    posts = ListField(ReferenceField("Post", dbref = False))
    #... a bunch of other fields

class UserProfile(Document):
    name = StringField()
    avatar = URLField()
```

I would like to have the same ObjectId for both the UserProfile and the User, so that I only need one ObjectId to reference both the User and the UserProfile.  After all, it's really a one-to-one relationship, and since a user can author many posts, I don't want to embed her profile in the posts themselves.  When creating a user document, I would immediately create the corresponding profile document like this:

```
john = User.objects.create(login = "john", password = "super!password")
john_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(id = john.id, name = "John Smith",
                avatar = "http://www.example.com/img/photo.jpg")
```

So far so good.  Now I have a `Post` document with an `author` field that references the `User` document:

```
class Post(Document):
    author = ReferenceField("User", dbref = False)
    text = StringField()
```

I would like to add an `author_profile` reference, based on the same ObjectId. I tried this:

```
class Post(Document):
    author = ReferenceField("User", dbref = False)
    author_profile = ReferenceField("User", db_field = "author", dbref = False)
    text = StringField()
```

But I get the following exception:

```
mongoengine.base.InvalidDocumentError: Multiple db_fields defined for: author
```

So it seems that I have to do so "manually".  Something like this perhaps:

```
class Post(Document):
    author = ReferenceField("User", dbref = False)
    text = StringField()
    @property
    def author_profile(self):
        if hasattr(self, "_author_profile"):
            return self._author_profile
        self._author_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(id = self._data["author"].id)
        return self._author_profile
```

I guess it's not that bad, but isn't there a better solution?

Thanks.

Note: I read the [mongodb documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-one-relationships-between-documents/) about one-to-one relationships, as well as the [mongoengine ReferenceField documentation](http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.ReferenceField), but it did not help me on this specific question.

Comment: Why you don't use login (I suppose that it's unique) as _id?

Comment: Yes I could, you're right, but I don't think that it fixes my problem: how would I implement `post.author` and `post.author_profile` ?  I need two ReferenceFields, one pointing to the User and the other pointing to the UserProfile, both with the same id (be it an objectid or a login).  You see my point?

Comment: I never worked with mongoengine, so unfortunately I can't help you with that. Also, I don't like to use DBRef because I prefer to control the relationships manually. I don't know if you're new to mongodb, but one important thing to keep in mind is not design data as in relational databases.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to store the same id twice to do this:

```
class Post(Document):
    author = ReferenceField("User", dbref = False)
    author_profile = ReferenceField("UserProfile", dbref = False)
    text = StringField()
```

I'm not sure if that brings any benefits to your solution - there maybe an improvement in the number of queries to dereference, but I'd have to test that!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing this:

```
def user_profile(reference_name):
    attrib_name = "_" + reference_name + "_profile"
    def user_profile_getter(self):
        if not hasattr(self, attrib_name):
            reference = self._data.get(reference_name, None)
            if not reference:
                return None
            setattr(self, attrib_name, UserProfile.objects.get(reference.id))
        return getattr(self, attrib_name)
    return property(user_profile_getter)
```

My `Post` class now looks like this:

```
class Post(Document):
    author = ReferenceField("User", dbref = False)
    author_profile = user_profile("author")
    text = StringField()
```

Whenever I add a `ReferenceField` that points to the `User` class, I also add such a `user_profile` (read-only) reference.  Note that if you only access the `author_profile`, it will not load the `author`, and vice versa.